# Remotely flag a node in Drupal 7 with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drupal, drupal-7

I've got a Drupal 7 website that I'm using as a backend, with the [flags module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag). In a nutshell, users can flag nodes and create lists of these flagged nodes. On the website, it's working wonderfully and I have no problems at all with it.

The problem is when I try to flag or unflag a node using AngularJS. I'm able to create and edit a node, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to flag or unflag it with a specific flag.

In the Views page where I can see the lists of what users have flagged, there's an option for whether something is flagged or not. The problem is that the same node could be flagged for one thing, but not the other. I can't find a way to differentiate between the two. "I have this!" and "I want this!" are the two different flags. If it was just one, then I could easily go the "Yep, this is flagged!" route.

Does anyone know a way to see *which* flag is, well, flagged? I get my result in a JSON using Views, and I'm using AngularJS 1.5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! To get started, I had to install and enable the [Flag Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_service) module. Then, I just enabled the flagging on my server.

After that, I am able to hit the endpoint

```
www.mywebsite.com/api/flag/flag.json
```

with a POST request. The headers I've included are the same I included when updating a Node, which are

```
Content-Type : application/json,
Cookie : Session Name = Session ID
X-CSRF-Token : www.example.com/?q=services/session/token
```

Then, the body

```
"flag_name" : "name",
"action" : "flag" (or "unflag"),
"entity_id" : node ID
```

This lets you flag or unflag a certain flag on the node. I'll leave this here in case anyone else runs into the same problem!